# Changing the library parameters of BSP with TCL in Xilinx SDK

Tags: tcl, xilinx, bsp, xsdk

I want to change the some of the configurable parameters of lwip and xilffs libraries with tcl commands in Xilinx SDK. I can get the configurable parameters of xilffs library via the command:

```
configbsp -bsp <bsp_name> -lib xilffs

========================================================================
                    NAME   VALUE
========================================================================
            enable_exfat   false
  enable_multi_partition   false
            fs_interface   1
         num_logical_vol   2
              ramfs_size   3145728
        ramfs_start_addr   
               read_only   false
            set_fs_rpath   0
               use_chmod   false
                 use_lfn   0
                use_mkfs   true
             use_strfunc   0
             word_access   true
```

For example how can I change the value of ***use_lfn*** parameter to 1 from command line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the first Google search result for [`configbsp`](https://www.xilinx.com/html_docs/xilinx2019_1/SDK_Doc/xsct/sdk/reference_sdk_configbsp.html), the syntax is this:

> ## Syntax
>
> **configbsp** [*OPTIONS*] [*<param-name>* [*<value>*]]
>
> If `<param-name>` and `<value>` are not specified, returns the details of all configurable parameters of processor, os, or all libraries in BSP. If `<param-name>` is specified and `<value>` value is not specified, return the value of the parameter. If `<param-name>` and `<value>` are specified, set the value of parameter.

That would lead me try:

```
configbsp -bsp <bsp_name> -lib xilffs use_lfn 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought we need to specify the library with -lib option because **we want to change the parameters of that library** but actually we don't. When I run the command

```
configbsp -bsp udp_bsp -lib xilffs use_lfn 1
```

I got the following error:

*conflicting options specified, use only one of -proc, -lib, -os or  value>*

But after I removed the -lib option

```
configbsp -bsp <bsp_name> use_lfn 1
```

It worked!!!!

```
configbsp -bsp udp_bsp -lib xilffs

========================================================================
                    NAME   VALUE
========================================================================
            enable_exfat   false
  enable_multi_partition   false
            fs_interface   1
         num_logical_vol   2
              ramfs_size   3145728
        ramfs_start_addr   
               read_only   false
            set_fs_rpath   0
               use_chmod   false
                 use_lfn   1
                use_mkfs   true
             use_strfunc   0
             word_access   true
```

Comment: After changing the parameter value we have to regenerate the bsp with the command:

`regenbsp -bsp <bsp_name>`